Is it possible to assign a render node programmatically to a mesh with the same centre?
Sorry if this question has been asked before however I cannot find the answer anywhere.
For some context:
I have a simulation software (python) that is building a 3D model. This model is then imported into Blender where I can neaten it up before it gets put into a script for displaying objects in 3D using JS (hosted on a website). This model is a GLTF export from Blender.
My current issue:
My current node mesh layout looks like this:

However I need each mesh to come with its own render node for some of the JS displays to be put near the mesh that they are linked to.  (at the moment they all merge together as it triagulates between the node and the mesh) I have roughly 2000 individual meshes and materials outputted ( this is not something I can change)  Does anyone have any advice on how I could complete this programatically ie is there a way to script this in Blender?
I am pretty new to scripting within Blender so any help would be greatly appreciated!
